# Hint not visible in Editbox while i run my app

Tags: android, hint, editbox

when i change it ,it is not reflected in the app when i test it

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="#EEEEEE"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:ems="10"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:hint="Entername"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="40dp"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
    android:paddingTop="40dp"
    android:textColorHint="#AAAAAA"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="italic" />
```

not able to see the hint as i have change it.

Comment: Try to replace this: android:hint"enter name" with this: android:hint="enter name".

Comment: Sorry guys i missed " = " while  edit but its not working this way 
. BTW a thought for the ppl who really thought missing = as solution

Comment: editText.setOnFocusListener(new OnFocusListener(){
      public void onFocus(){
        editText.setHint("");
       }
    });


this is the solution to the prob

Answer (score 2):

You have forgot "=" sign with Hint attribute.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="#EEEEEE"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:ems="10"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:hint="Entername"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="40dp"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
    android:paddingTop="40dp"
    android:textColorHint="#AAAAAA"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="italic" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you missed =

change this line

```
android:hint"enter name"
```

to this

```
android:hint = "enter name"
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing = symbol
replace this `android:hint"enter name"`  `with android:hint="enter name"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
editText.setOnFocusListener(new OnFocusListener(){
  public void onFocus(){
    editText.setHint("");
  }
});
```

Comment: Bro 
editText.setOnFocuschange(new OnFocuschange(){
  public void onFocus(){
    editText.setHint("");
  }
});

Answer (score 0):

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="#EEEEEE"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:ems="10"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:hint="Entername"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="40dp"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
    android:paddingTop="40dp"
    android:textColorHint="#AAAAAA"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="italic" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You mistyped `hint`, maybe typo error

It should look like this

```
android:hint = "enter name"
```

where you had written it as `android:hint  "enter name"`. Missing **"="**